# Django Mock an imported function used in a class function as part of a unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

So I'm writing tests for my django application and I have successfully mocked quite a few external api calls that aren't needed for tests however one is tripping me up which is send_sms.  To start here is the code:

`a/models.py`:

```
from utils.sms import send_sms
...
class TPManager(models.Manager):
  def notification_for_job(self, job):
    ...
    send_sms()

...
class TP(models.Model):
  objects = TPManager()
    ...
```

`p/test_models.py`:

```
  @patch('a.models.send_sms')
  @patch('p.signals.send_mail')
  def test_tradepro_review_job_deleted(self, send_mail, send_sms):
    job = Job.objects.create(
            tradeuser=self.tradeuser, 
            location=location, 
            category=category,
            details="sample details for job"
        )
```

The Job object creation triggers `TP.objects.notification_for_job` via its `perform_create` method here:

`p/views.py`:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        job = serializer.save(tradeuser=self.request.user.tradeuser)
        if settings.DEV_MODE:
            from a.models import TP
            job.approved = True
            job.save()
            TP.objects.notification_for_job(job)
```

I have tried mocking `a.models.TP.objects.notification_for_job`, `utils.sms.send_sms`, `a.models.TPManger.notification_for_job` all to no avail.  This is a pretty complex flow but I believe I have tried the main mock candidates here and was wondering if anybody knows how to either mock the `notification_for_job` function or `send_sms` function properly mostly just to prevent these api call that inevitably fail due to my test environment.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!